# Race condition trying to sync access token in multiple tab

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, access-token, next.js, refresh-token

Here’s what I’m facing. Currently, refresh tokens are stored in httpOnly cookie, and on every SSR, we refresh the token and send the whole response to the browser, the access token is only saved in memory, then the browser will continue for renewing it. The problem arises when we have 2 tabs, the access tokens will go out of sync. The initial tab’s access token will be unusable.

To work around this, we can either use localStorage to sync the tokens or use non-httpOnly cookie to store the access tokens. Or,  manage tokens server-side, But both would have a problem, let’s say Tab 1 sent a request using the current access token, then I open Tab 2, the token is refreshed, Tab 1 request just reached the API, and the token is already invalidated.

I can’t find a proper solution unless we build more server-side logic into NextJS. Or perhaps if we don’t invalidate access token when refreshing and let it dies off the expiry. That way, we have ample time to fight the race condition.

Or, we retry all requests using exponential back off. Actually this kinda solves everything, and there’s a package ready for it. Except we’ll need to rewrite many parts to adopt the new library, and also there would be false alarms in the logs.

Or, we just ignore this and hope the race condition won’t appear, although it seems to me it’s going to occur pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

We are facing this problem in the company I work for.

Our solution is to store the refresh token in localStorage. If the token is regenerated, the other open tabs would detect a change in localStorage, retrieve the stored token (which now is a brand new one, generated by some other tab) and from that point on use it. The token is stored in memory until another change in localStorage is triggered.

To learn how to detect a change in storage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event

Honestly, there is no standard and robust solution to that as far as I know, and based on my research on the Internet.

Comment: I actually employed a similar method but in a form of this library https://github.com/noderaider/localsync it's been far too long since I last faced this problem, I assumed things have been doing well hopefully

Comment: storing refresh token in localStorage is a security risk for Cross-Site Scripting Attacks...